# EL and covariant return types

Tags: jsf-2, el, covariance

i have these classes

```
public abstract class Unit
{
    public abstract UnitType getType();

    ...
}

public class Item extends Unit
{
    protected ItemType type;

    @Override
    public ItemType getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(ItemType type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    ...
}
```

and obvoiusly `ItemType` extends `UnitType`.

and i get:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /WEB-INF/facelets/general.xhtml @23,165 value="#{bean.item.type}": The class 'com.example.Item' does not have a writable property 'type'.
```

i can understand that covariant return type can confuse EL (2.2), so is this a bug?

i can workaround this using

1. generics
2. change setType signature to `public void setType(UnitType type)` and check instanceof inside
3. change method name to avoid override

is there a REAL solution instead of workarounds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bean property 'xxx' is not writable or has an invalid setter method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888588/bean-property-xxx-is-not-writable-or-has-an-invalid-setter-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `java.beans.Introspector` is responsible. There were a lot of relevant bugs in Java: 
[7092744](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7092744), [7122138](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7122138), [6528714](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6528714), [6794807](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6794807), [6788525](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6788525). Problems manifest with covariant return types and generics due to synthetic bridge methods. With some Java 7 updates (45, 51, 67, 71) problems manifest not right way but after running the server for some time - this is probably related to softly/weakly referenced caches in the Introspector and related classes.

All these problems seem to be fixed in Java 1.7.0_80 (tested with Mojarra 2.2.8 and Wildfly 8.2.0.Final).