# Debugging JSF ManagedProperty NullPointer

Tags: jsf-2, el

Using JSF 2 on JBoss AS 7

Getting the following error:

```
07:36:39,579 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-/172.20.91.126:12580-16) 
Error Rendering View[/views/afgarendesok.xhtml]:
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: 
Unable to set property searchManager for managed bean afgArendeBacking 
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder$BakedBeanProperty.set(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:615)
```

The searchManager property is defined in the AfgArendeBacking class as:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{afgArendeSokManager}")
private AfgArendeSokManager searchManager;

@Override
public AfgArendeSokManager getSearchManager() {
  return searchManager;
}

public void setSearchManager(AfgArendeSokManager searchManager) {
  this.searchManager = searchManager;
}
```

The AfgArendeSokManager is a @ManagedBean that is @SessionScoped.

Two things I don't get.  One is why the error shuts down all usage of JSF not just for the session producing the error.  The error seems to appear after non-usage both below the default session timeout and beyond.  The other odd this is that a null pointer exception at line 606 in the BakedBeanProperty has to be the one the writeMethod variable.  That variable is created via the PropertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod() call.  This should have bombed earlier when creating baked bean (i.e. bakeBeanProperty method).

Any ideas how to debug?  The property "searchManager" is resolved correctly since we can use the JSF views normally (both the getter/setter exist).

The search manager is our session scratch pad for propagating stuff between view and request scoped backing beans.

Comment: I see an `@Override`, maybe a covariant return type?

Comment: AfgArendeBacking extends an abstract class forcing the a method signature of:
  public AfgAbstraktSokManager getSearchManager();

where AfgArendeSokManager extends the AfgAgstraktSokManager.

Comment: There you are. EL does not deal very well with covariants. Try with a pair of getter/setter that does not override, ie getSearchManager2/setSearchManager2 (see here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039396/el-and-covariant-return-types)

Comment: Alright.  Will look into it.  Do you know of an blog/documentation that touches on why EL has trouble with covariants?

Answer (score 1):

The article explains the issue of using reflection to access methods with covariant return types (see here: https://dzone.com/articles/covariant-return-type-abyssal). The article relates to Java 6 but the background information is very useful.

The issue you're facing and that hit us just this week (using Java 1.7.0_40) is not one of EL but of the java.beans.Introspector.