# spring framework upgrade updating context bean names

Tags: spring-framework-beans

I am upgrading Spring 1.2 to 5.3 and I had to download lot of dependency files. Finally I am getting an error when starting the server as "Bean property 'sessionForm' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?". After I remove it, I get next one "commandName" etc. How can I replace the below ?

```
<bean id="priceIncreaseForm" class="web.PriceIncreaseFormController">
    <property name="sessionForm"><value>true</value></property>
    <property name="commandName"><value>priceIncrease</value></property>
    <property name="commandClass"><value>bus.PriceIncrease</value></property>
    <property name="validator"><ref bean="priceIncreaseValidator"/></property>
    <property name="formView"><value>priceincrease</value></property>
    <property name="successView"><value>hello.htm</value></property>
    <property name="productManager">
        <ref bean="prodMan"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Hello, At least, can you please give a clue how to resolve this issue ? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the controller and the Exception? There's not much to go on here..

Comment: same problem, maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888588/bean-property-xxx-is-not-writable-or-has-an-invalid-setter-method

Comment: Thank you!, Could you please take a look at my other post ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69918472/spring-framework-no-adapter-for-handler.