# Spring framework No adapter for handler

Tags: spring-mvc

I am upgrading Spring framework from very old version to 5.3 - I made updated to controller and configuration file. I am getting "javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler for Controller" error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd">
       
     <context:component-scan base-package="abc.controller,abc.bean,abc.bean.command,abc.validator" />    
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />    
    
  
    <!-- Controllers -->
    <bean id="uploadFormController" class="abc.controller.UploadFormController">      
      <property name="mailSender"><ref bean="mailSender"/></property>
      <property name="message"><ref bean="uploadConfirmationEmail"/></property> 
      <property name="submissionDao"><ref bean="submissionDao"/></property>
      <property name="providerDao"><ref bean="providerDao"/></property>
    </bean>
    
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="urlMap">            
        </property>
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="securityInterceptor"/>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="upload.html">starSiSpreadsheetUploadFormController</prop>                
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="securityInterceptor"
          class="abc.interceptor.SecurityInterceptor">
      <property name="defaultUser"><value>${abc.defaultUser}</value></property>
    </bean>        
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
           <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
        </property>
        <property name="prefix"><value>/jsp/</value></property>
        <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
    </bean>  
    
</beans>`

    package abc.controller;


    @Controller 
    @RequestMapping("/upload.html")
    public class UploadFormController { 
            
    @Autowired
    private SpreadsheetUpload bean; //CommandClass
    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;
    @Autowired
    private SimpleMailMessage message;
    @Autowired
    private SubmissionDAO submissionDao;
    @Autowired
    private ProviderDAO providerDao;
    
    
    protected String onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors)
                throws Exception 
    {
        // let's see if there's a provider
        if (bean.getProvider() == null)
        {
            log.info("No provider selected.");
            throw new DataEntryException("No provider selected.  ");
        }
        
        return "redirect:upload.html";      
    }

        protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception 
        {
        // TODO - switch code over to using LDAP queries
          HttpSession session = request.getSession();       
           //Logic goes here..              
            Map map = new HashMap();        
            map.put("admin", admin);        
            return map;
        }
        }
```

Could someone take a look and help me on this? I have been trying since last two days and no luck so far. Thank you!

Comment: I also have tried below code but no luck. Can you please take a look?. Thank you!
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload.html", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    protected Map getData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{}

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in my code. I have another method called "OnSubmit" which is causing the problem.